# How to request a permission from a Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am trying to request a permission on my **Service**. Usually to request a permission I have to pass an Activity. My application does not have an `Activity`.

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {    
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
    }
}
```

How can I do it from a Service?

Comment: How come I was downvoted? This is a valid question. Please explain, if I am wrong I will gladly remove my question.

Answer (score 1):

Request for permission from a service has no sense. Take notice that you ask for permission to a user when application needs to access to some system functionality, so you must request user for permission in your activity and then start your service.

Comment: If you find that your service lacks permission sometime after it was started -- for example, the service is kicked off by `JobScheduler` -- you can raise a `Notification` to prompt the user to grant you permission, then quietly shut down your service.

Comment: My application does not have an `Activity`.

Comment: "Request for permission from a service has no sense." Since my application has no `Activity` then it does it make sense for me to request in the `Service`.

Comment: @BlueNite: "Since my application has no Activity" -- then you have bigger problems. Your app simply will never run, unless it is pre-installed on some device or serves as a plugin for some other app. An explicit `Intent` needs to be used to start one of your components; until then, none of your manifest-registered receivers will work, and nothing else is going to start your service.

Comment: Bruh, A MediaLibraryService can be a standalone Service and it needs permission to access the data on the phone if it is using the user's music as the library.

Comment: @CommonsWare You can write Services that respond to Intents; see the MediaLibraryService

Comment: @JohnGlen: I did not claim otherwise. An explicit `Intent` is still needed to start one of the components, and until then, none of the manifest-registered receivers will work. That explicit `Intent` can, and sometimes does, come from a core OS process. While I am not familiar with `MediaLibraryService`, it's certainly possible that a media process starts that service via an explicit `Intent`.